# How to edit a comment using jQuery?

Tags: jquery, html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript">
     $(function() {
      $('.companyInfo').append('<textarea value="save" class="textArea"></textarea>');
      $('.companyInfo').append('<button class="saveme">save</button>');
      $('.saveme').click(function() {
        var text = $('.textArea').val();
        $('.newDiv').append('<p><input type="button" class="edit" value="edit">'+text+'</p>');
      $('.edit').click(function() {
        var result = $(this).parent().text();
        var $textarea = $('<textarea class="textArea2"></textarea><button class="save">save</button>');
        $textarea.val(result) 
        $(this).parent().html($textarea);
          $('.save').click(function() {
            var textInner = $('.textArea2').val();
            $(this).parent().parent().html('<p><input type="button" class="edit" value="edit">'+textInner+'</p>');
          })
      })
      })
    })
</script>
    <div class='companyInfo'></div>

    <div class="newDiv"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

I am trying to create a comment box where users can add comment, and can edit the comment as many as they need after saving it to the DOM. The above solution works, however it only lets the user edit a comment once, so if you try to edit the comment twice, it does not let you do that.

I cannot figure out how to make the edit button work more just once. Does anyone have an idea how ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your approach works only once because you're dynamically removing elements when you replace the innerHTML of the parent tag. Thus, the associated event listener also gets lost. To fix this, change your listeners from `$(selector).click(function() { });` to `$(document).on('click', selector, function() { });`

Comment: I tried, it did not work. I not sure if it is because it is nested.

Comment: @Max I've updated my answer. I re-read your question. Try now

Comment: Thanks a lot  Mehul